# Taking care of transparency using IMagick via PHP makes some images darker

Tags: php, imagick

I have a script that handles/scales uploaded images. I noticed that some of the images come out significantly darkened, and through a process of elimination tracked the darkening back to this section of code:

```
            $scaled = new IMagick();
            $scaled->newPseudoImage($original->getImageWidth(), $original->getImageHeight(), 'xc:white');
            $scaled->compositeImage($original,  Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0);
            $scaled->flattenImages();
```

What I'm doing here is trying to eliminate issues with transparent backgrounds in some images coming through as black when I convert to jpg.

Does anyone have any idea which part of this code is darkening the image and what a good way to fix it might be?

Edit: Still haven't figured out the heart of this issue, but I did find that I can avoid doing this to images that don't need it by wrapping it in:

```
                if($original->getImageAlphaChannel()){
```

Comment: Can you post an example image?

Comment: @Sherms  Did you got any solution?

Comment: Sorry @AlauddinAhmed, it's been over four years and I've lost whatever context this was.

Comment: I found a solution. Checkout this answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51402288/image-gets-darker-in-imagick