# Image gets darker in imagick

Tags: php, imagick

I need help (My english is not good, please try to understand what i'm trying to find). Currently i'm working in a project based on image transformation, where i'm using imagick to transform image. I'm successfully transformed my image. What i am doing in my project is taking a photo([photo1](https://ibb.co/i2YDjJ)), placing it to another photo ([photo2](https://ibb.co/cKmoJd) {the grey are is transparent}) which create the following effect [photo3](https://ibb.co/bLVyJd). Then replaceing it again with photo2 (to create the mask effect which showing the hand), and the result is ([photo4](https://ibb.co/kzOM4J)). But the problem is, photo1 area in photo4 gets darker. {Please compare photo3 and photo4}. Can anyone help me how to keep the original color of photo1 in photo4. Here is my code:

```
$image1 = new imagick( public_path("img/testImage2.jpg") );
$image2 = new imagick( public_path("storage/Templates/romantisch copy.png"));
$image3 = new imagick( public_path("storage/Templates/romantisch copy.png") );


//for preserving transparency
$image2->mergeImageLayers(\Imagick::LAYERMETHOD_FLATTEN);
$image3->mergeImageLayers(\Imagick::LAYERMETHOD_FLATTEN);

//resizing photo1
$image1->resizeImage(468, 729, Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1);

/* Fill background area with transparent */
$image1->setImageVirtualPixelMethod(Imagick::VIRTUALPIXELMETHOD_TRANSPARENT);
// $image2->setImageVirtualPixelMethod(Imagick::VIRTUALPIXELMETHOD_TRANSPARENT);
$image1->setImageArtifact('compose:args', "1,0,-0.5,0.5");

$image1->setImageMatte(true);
$controlPoints = array(
    0, 0, //initial point (top left)
    0, 0, //targeted point (top left)

    0, $image1->getImageHeight(), //initial point (bottom left)
    0, $image1->getImageHeight(), //targeted point (bottom left)

    $image1->getImageWidth(), 0, //initial point (top right)
    $image1->getImageWidth(), 0, //targeted point (top right)

    $image1->getImageWidth(), $image1->getImageHeight(), //initial point (bottom right)
    $image1->getImageWidth(), $image1->getImageHeight() //targeted point (bottom right)
);

// /* Perform the distortion */
$image1->distortImage(Imagick::DISTORTION_PERSPECTIVE, $controlPoints, true);

$image2->compositeImage($image1, Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 720, 368);
$image2->compositeImage($image3, Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0, 0);

/* Ouput the image */
header("Content-Type: image/png");
$image2->writeImage ("test_0.png");
echo $image2;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my solution. Changing my colorspace solved the problem. still don't know why.

```
$image2->transformImageColorspace(\Imagick::COLORSPACE_XYZ);
$image3->transformImageColorspace(\Imagick::COLORSPACE_XYZ);
```